# How to Add Two Columns But Keep Rows Not Equal

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I add two columns (amount, amount2) if they have the same value in multiple columns (Account,Account2) using UPDATE statement. I want to keep all rows even if Account <> Account 2. Also i want them in two columsn only Account and Amount. I am using MS Access sql view.

For example: I want to add Amount and Amount2 columns only if Account, Account 2 columns match.

I want that result end to be only two columns, the Account and the amount that was added together.

```
Account Amount Account2 Amount2
1234576  4      1234576    4
4444444  10     4564888    11
456789   2      456789      2
000000   1      1111111     6
```

Comment: How do you decide the Amount values?

Comment: When the account numbers are equal then add them. If they are not equal keep them. Basically any duplicate account numbers should be added and still keep the rest.

Comment: `update tablename set Amount2 = Amount where Account = Account2`?

Comment: Hi Jarlh that works but only adds the equal values and the not equal rows do not show on the updated table.

Comment: It might help if you tell us just a little about the context of this requirement.  To be honest, it sounds like an interview or homework question.  It may also be helpful to provide examples of the data before and after the operation (that is, show what it does look like, and show what it should look like).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using a `iif` statement:

```
select account, 
       amount + iif(account = account2, amount2, 0) as amount
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT t1.Account as Acct, Sum(t1.Amount) as Amt1, first(t1.Account2) as Acct2, sum(t1.amount) as Amt2 
FROM test as t1
WHERE t1.Amount=t1.Amount2
GROUP BY t1.Account
ORDER BY t1.Account)

UNION

(SELECT t2.Account as Acct, sum(t2.Amount) as Amt1, first(t2.Account2) as Acct2, sum(t2.amount2) as Amt2
FROM test as t2
WHERE t2.Amount <> t2.Amount2
GROUP BY t2.account
ORDER BY t2.account)
```

Comment: if you're only get half the answer then the other half has to be the inverse.  Join them with a UNION

Comment: Thank you geeFlo. Would this work if i want to use UPDATE?

Comment: Hmmm, never tried UPDATE with a UNION.  Would think you would want to update to a secondary table to preserve your input table.